# Should the link for fetch request be hidden?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, fetch-api

I'm developing a website using React. Say the link I use for the fetch request is http://localhost:3000/users for development and https://www.mywebsite.com/users for production. It's for a get request to get the list of users so I can display it on my website. The website visitors will only see the production version through the browser. Or, someone might find out my github repository somehow. Since my front end code is public, they can see that they can use that link to get the list of users themselves. However, what if the fetch request is for something I only want it to go through the website? I have a post request that updates the user's balance. For example, https://www.mywebsite.com/change_balance. If someone looks at my code and makes a successful fetch request themselves, they can cheat the system and have their desired balance. Should I have the links in a file outside the git repository?

I put the links for the fetch requests in a file and export them to App.js so that I don't have to keep changing back and forth with the development code and production code.

Links file

```
const links = ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://www.mywebsite.com'];

export default links;
```

Declaring a variable for a single link after importing so that I only have to change this when switching to production

```
const link = links[0];
```

One of my fetch requests using async await

```
const response = await fetch(`${link}/users`);
// rest of the code
```

I have my links file inside my git repository. If I move it outside the repo, the visitors shouldn't be able to see it if they check the code with their browsers, although it would still be in the git history. Am I just being paranoid and should I not change anything? I don't want to make my github repo private.

Comment: Authenticate the requests from your site. You cannot hide the URLs in the final HTML, but you can check if the request received on that URL has a “permission” to request that resource (be it a GET, PUSH or anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never trust the client. No matter what. IP spoofing to basic header modification is common. All restrictions and validations need to be on the server side. You should safely assume that if you have a public API it can and will be called from various sources.

Some solutions:

- Authentication
- CSRF (which can still be mimicked outside of your app)